# Is there a way to receive notifications for threads you have starred?

Tags: feature-request

Now and then I click the star button for questions I think are useful, even if I don't participate directly in them. Is there a way to receive notifications whenever a new answer is added to these questions? Right now, I have to go to my profile and check each starred item manually. It's not a convenient process for checking topics I'm interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently, a "follow" option has been added (see `follow` next to `edit` below the body of the question).

For more info see [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/299332).

Comment: Thank you. I assume I should retrospectively follow the threads I starred.

Comment: Very odd that SE decided to separate the concepts of starring and following.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie The Meta post says, they are planning on rebranding the starring as "bookmarking". I personally don't really use bookmarks, but I guess it sort of makes sense to have an SE-internal bookmark for questions you liked. If you're a heavy bookmarker, you might not want to be notified of all comments / new answers for all the questions you starred/bookmarked.